# Are all bluetooth adapters the same?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have a wireless bluetooth mouse which I'm not using. It used to have a bluetooth adapter with it, which I lost a long time ago ... (don't ask). Since my regular mouse just died (bad contact in cable from messing with it too much) I was thinking of buying just the new generic bluetooth adapter ?

Are all those adapters the same thing ? Or can this that came with the mouse be somehow different ?

---

Edit by ldigas: How would one find out what bluetooth standard/class/adapter one needs ?
(I don't see anything useful written on the sticker on the [mouse](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/mice_pointers/mice/devices/3287&cl=us,en)).

Or to put it bluntly - will it work with [this one](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=276&pl1_id=13&pl2_id=75) in your opinion ?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your edit.

Answer (score 2):

> Are all bluetooth adapters the same ?

No, there is quite a variety of different bluetooth standards:

**[Bluetooth: Specifications and features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Specifications_and_features)**

Some, but not all, are backwards compatible to certain standards.

### Update

The V470 Cordless Laser Mouse is compatible  with multiple BT standards and so is the EB-MDC1, so there's a great likelihood for a match. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different Bluetooth adapters, many have different chipsets and specifications (such as speed, distance (Class) EDR support along with other things).

However, if your mouse follows a set standard that the new Bluetooth adapter supports, it should work without problems.

I have used a generic Bluetooth class 2+EDR adapter (I think the most common/cheapest) with off the shelf Bluetooth mice and not had a problem.

### Edit

Update to your edit -

It Should work fine with that one... class and various other things mainly affect the speed, distance and a few other technical things (such as pairing) that the device uses. Actually supporting devices should be no problem, depending on the [software stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack) you use (Blue Soleil, Toshiba, Microsoft etc.) - The mouse should simply support the profile "HID / Human Interface Device) and work with any 1.2+ Bluetooth hardware or software stack out there.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is bluetooth (at least as far as mice are concerned). However, was the mouse really Bluetooth? Most cordless mice are not actually Bluetooth, but rather are proprietary wireless technology. If they lack the Bluetooth logo, they're probably not Bluetooth.